# My Task is not waiting for completion

Tags: c#, asynchronous

**Thanks for all the replies, I really appreciate it and learned a lot! I also learned that I have so much to learn and will be hitting the books.**

I'm still trying to get the hang of await and async so I have been messing around but I'm stumped right now. I have done a lot of googling, reading, and research but I can't find the issue.

So what I am doing is deserializing and trying to return an object

```
    public static async Task<SomeObject> Deserialize(string filePath)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadFile(filePath));

        await task;

        return task.Result;
    }
```

The method above is then called here:

```
public async Task DoStuff()
    {
        var load = await Helper.Deserialize(Helper.filePath);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(load.GetType());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code runs before the task is completed and the object always comes out as null, rendering it useless. I know I am doing something wrong but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what it is even after spending hours reading answered questions and the microsoft docs.

@Fabio Here is the LoadFile method:

```
        private static SomeObject LoadFile(string path)
    {
        JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(path));

        var obj = json.Deserialize(reader, typeof(SomeObject));
        reader.Close();

        return (SomeObject)obj;
    }
```

Comment: try remove the await task, instead return task from the deserialize func.

Comment: I'd suggest making `LoadFile` `async` and `await` the `async` versions of whatever IO calls it makes instead.  What you're doing is really meant for CPU bound tasks https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

Comment: Can you show `LoadFile` method?

Comment: @Fabio Yea, of course. I added it to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

```
public static Task<SomeObject> DeserializeAsync(string filePath)
{
   return Task.Run(() => LoadFile(filePath));
}
```

assuming `LoadFile` returns `SomeObject`

Or you can refactor the `LoadFile` method

```
private static Task<SomeObject> LoadFileAsync(string path) {
    return Task.Run(() => {
        JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
        using(var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(path))) {
            var obj = json.Deserialize(reader, typeof(SomeObject));
            return (SomeObject)obj;
        }
    });        
}

public static async Task<SomeObject> DeserializeAsync(string filePath)
{
   var obj = await LoadFileAsync(filePath);
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply, I am trying that right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post. That fixed my problem, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: OP's code samples should work, even with `Task.Factory.StartNew..` - but of course using `Task.Run` is correct way for creating tasks. Sorry I don't see why wrapping code in two tasks will solve a problem. Can you explain?

Comment: @Fabio I was showing how to do it one way or the other. I agree wrapping in two tasks makes no sense and it was not my intention.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static Task<SomeObject> Deserialize(string filePath)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => LoadFile(filePath));

        return task;       
    }
```